Trying to make a pointer MUI dialog
I am trying to create a MUI dialog that looks like this:

The customers idea is the dialog is point to button or section on the main page as a reminder the the user.   But I am no seeing an option in MUI to create this type/shape of dialog.   So is there any examples of someone creating something like this?
